# How can I access data loaded in Application_Start from a user session?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, session, global-variables, session-variables, global-asax

At the moment I load data into ASP.NET MVC user sessions when the respective user session starts. The data is a table from a database containing a few dozens of rows - all users use the same data. Now I'd like to move this code from the session start into `Application_Start`, as it is the same for all users and I only want to load it once when the application starts.

How can I do this? Can I globally provide data loaded during `Application_Start` so it can be used in a user session? Would I have to use caching or is there another possibility?

Comment: using a static class would help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Application variable.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Name"] = "Value";
```